# rename DAT file using bat command

Tags: batch-file

I have a DAT file that I need to rename and make a txt file. It currently is named PRV4W.SW and I want it to be PRV4WSW.txt. I've tried below but it does not seem to work. Thanks.

```
ren "C:\PRV 4\20200731\PRV4W.SW" "C:\PRV 4\20200731\PRV4WSW.txt"

ren "C:\PRV 4\20200731\PRV4W.SW.dat" "C:\PRV 4\20200731\PRV4WSW.txt"
```

Comment: Read the output of `ren /?`. The second parameter (destination) doesn't support any folder information, just a new name: `ren "C:\PRV 4\20200731\PRV4W.SW.dat" "PRV4WSW.txt"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
ren "C:\PRV 4\20200731\PRV4W.SW" PRV4WSW.txt
```

The above command works fine in Win7.

BTW, the new name should not contain [drive:][path]

Please type

```
help ren
```

for the usage of the ren command.

Comment: Thanks. that was it.